# Can I actually spray paint my Apple Watch Sport gold?

Tags: apple-watch

I saw that [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/MMF9I_9DAcs) where a guy paints his Sport Edition Watch with gold spray paint. Is it safe to do this?

Cause if you look at 1:57 of the video the spray goes in the microphone holes. I really wanna do this on my watch too. It looks awesome but I just don't wanna damage my Apple Watch.

Comment: The people that did that have twitter accounts. Have you asked them how it went?

Answer (score 13):

> To gild refined gold, to paint the lily,
>   To throw a perfume on the violet,
>   To smooth the ice, or add another hue
>   Unto the rainbow, or with taper-light
>   To seek the beauteous eye of heaven to garnish,
>   Is wasteful and ridiculous excess.
>
> *Wm. Shakespeare.*

Comment: Beautiful, and so, so true

Comment: I can't make this answer any better. Well done

Comment: The OP is asking if it's possible and safe, you don't answer that.

Comment: @theonlygusti - I saw no point whatsoever in lending any credence to such a ridiculous idea. Yours is the first downvote in two years, so let's assume no-one else did either.

Comment: What's with the two-years-late down votes? Tell you what... try it & report back how it went... after all, they're only cheap...

Answer (score 7):

Is it possible to paint your watch gold? **yes**.

Is it a smart thing to do?  *questionable*.

If you are good at spray painting you could do this.
It is possible that if your spray too much in the right spot, like around buttons, it could leak into the watch.

I would not suggest it because if you have issues with your watch it will void the warranty on your watch because you painted the watch, and looking up your serial number will show the color of the watch. If you don't mind voiding the warranty on your watch and you are really good at spray painting then you can go for it.

Personally, I would not do it.

Comment: Based on tests involving multiple laps in a pool, I highly doubt spray paint will be able to get inside. Water couldn't, and water is better at that than spray paint.

Answer (score 1):

I would be seriously concerned about the aftermath of the paint-job. It is advisable that you check the water-proof information of the watch. Even though paint is more viscous that water, I personally won't do it. I would still be doubtful about the harm the paint chemicals can do to my hands or the material of the watch itself.

So I advise that we stay happy in what god has given us and not run after fake gold.